# Test Cases not failing even if it has actually failed using Selenium TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I am using selenium appium for testing mobile application. One of my tests is register user which has actually failed, but it shows as passed in my eclipse console.

```
    @Test
    public void registerNewUserFromSignInPage() {
        try {
            String app_package_name = "com.xyz.abc:id/";


            By signInBtn = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_sign_in");
            System.out.println("Clicking on Sign in button");
            driver.findElement(signInBtn).click();

            By registerFromSignInPage = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_signuptrial");
            System.out.println("Register from Sign in page");
            driver.findElement(registerFromSignInPage).click();
            //Launch Page
            By registerBtn = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_register");
            System.out.println("Clicking on register button");
            driver.findElement(registerBtn).click();

            //Register screen
            By btn_signup_email = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_signup_email");
            System.out.println("Clicking on signup email button");
            driver.findElement(btn_signup_email).click();
            //Signup Screen
            By fullname = By.id(app_package_name + "et_name");
            System.out.println("Typing Full name");
            driver.findElement(fullname).sendKeys("Test QA");

            By email = By.id(app_package_name + "et_email");
            System.out.println("Typing Mail ID");
            driver.findElement(email).sendKeys("testqa@test.com");

            By passwrd = By.id(app_package_name + "et_password");
            System.out.println("Typing password");
            driver.findElement(passwrd).sendKeys("samplepassword");

            By submitBtn = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_signup");
            System.out.println("Clicking on Submit button");
            driver.findElement(submitBtn).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            By successMessage = By.id(app_package_name + "tv_success_text");
            boolean result = driver.findElement(successMessage).isDisplayed();
            System.out.println("The success message is displayed: " + result);
            String text = driver.findElement(successMessage).getText();
            System.out.println("The success message text is : " + text);

            By btnTC = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_tc");
            By nextBtn = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_next");
            By selectOption = By.id(app_package_name + "cb_none");
            By selectGender = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_male");
            By selectHeight = By.id(app_package_name + "et_height   ");
            By selectWeight = By.id(app_package_name + "et_weight");
            By selectEthnicity = By.id(app_package_name + "et_ethinicity");
            By selectEthnicityOption = By.id(app_package_name + "select_dialog_listview");
            By submitDetails = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_submit");
            By startApp = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_startapp");
            By firstEntry = By.id(app_package_name + "fabMain");
            By logFood = By.id(app_package_name + "fab_food");
            By gotTutorial = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_dialog_tutorial_ok");

            //signin page
            By username = By.id(app_package_name + "et_email");
            By password = By.id(app_package_name + "et_password");
            By signIn = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_sign_in");
            By register = By.id(app_package_name + "btn_signuptrial");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

In console it shows me the expected error:-

> An element could not be located on the page using the given search
>   parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 41 milliseconds

But, Test Case is displayed as :- **PASSED**: **registerNewUserFromSignInPage**

Comment: Because it inside `try catch` block.

Comment: it is in try and catch block, that's why even if any exception is found is it is considered to be handled inside catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not **asserting** anything here. In general, don't try to catch the errors in test cases. If the test fails because of any error. Let it fail. For the record, unless you have a Assertion the test will remain pass.